# Symmetric operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $B$ the operator defined by $B= i\frac{d}{dx}$ with domain

$$\mathcal{D}(B)=\{f\in W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R})~\hbox{such that}~f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}.$$

I ask about the domain of the adjoint of this operator?
and this operator is-it symmetric in this domain?

Comment: I am confused by your definition of the domain of $B$, because $f \in W^{2,2}$ already implies $f' \in  L^2$.

Comment: and if I correct the domain of B, what's the domain of the adjoint

Comment: The operator on $W^{1,2}$ is selfadjoint. The operator on $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is symmetric with adjoint that has domain $W^{1,2}$.